# Scheduling Assistant tool API

Tags: email, exchange-server, schedule

I'm looking for a way to get an information about user's schedule. There is a scheduling assistant tool that retrieves other user's schedule from the same email server. Is it the only interface to that kind of data? May be schedules are accessible via some protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using third party libraries like JWebDAV for Exchange

For Exchange 2003 use “JWebDAV for Exchange. Examples:

http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebdav/tutorial/getfreebusyforspecifiedusers.html

For Exchange 2007/2010/2013 use “JWebServices for Exchange”. Examples

http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/getavailability.html